# Run application in different modes

Tags: java, spring, groovy, java-8

My application should work in 2 modes: standard and custom.

I am using the same classes but it can react little bit differently in different modes.

How better to inject this mode into all(not all but a lot) classes?

Application should be switched in run-time.
Not boot time.

I am using java8 and groovy.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe with a bool flag?

Comment: spring profiles - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: Kevin: yes for me it is like a bool flag

Comment: Igor: After small investigation of requirements I got that  I need to have a runtime switch, not a boot time one, like profiles are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Igor, probably spring profiles would be helpful for you. Also, I could suggest maven profiles (in case if you use maven as a build tool of course). For example, if you have two different modes "production" and "development" you can create two directories with property file props.properties and do the following with maven:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <resource.location>classpath:production</resource.location>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <properties>
            <resource.location>classpath:development</resource.location>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

After this you are free to configure your spring property placeholer in this way

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${resource.location}/props.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

And build you app with

```
mvn install -Pdevelopment 
mvn install -Pproduction
```

As per runtime switch, could you provide more details on your application. In case if it is a web application you could create some webservice for switching modes.